# Keyboard Issue in Landscape Orientation - Xcode - Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, uikeyboard

I have a Share extension for my iOS app and the extension requires the use of a keyboard. It seems as though I cannot control the orientation of the view controller of the extension, so when the device is put in landscape mode, the keyboard turns sideways, but off the screen. This makes it so that the user cannot use the keyboard when in landscape mode. How can I change the coordinates of the keyboard on screen, and how do I detect the orientation of the device? I am perplexed by this issue and any feedback would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- To detect the orientation:

  ```
  if(UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation))
  {            
      println("landscape")
  }

  if(UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation))
  {
      println("portrait")
  }
  ```
- To detect the orientation change (in a UIViewController):

  ```
  override func didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation(fromInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation) {
      // your code
  }
  ```

You can detect the orientation change and the orientation you have

Comment: Thanks, and any idea how to change the keyboard coordinates?

Comment: Can you show me a screenshot of your stuck keyboard? :)

Comment: The keyboard isn't stuck, it's basically just not shown on the screen. In portrait mode it's normal, and when the device is turned, the keyboard turns in landscape, but falls below the screen. Any idea? If you still need a pic I can provide that.

Comment: Thanks. I'm just having trouble converting that code into swift, particularly these lines:
CGSize keyboardSize = [[[notification userInfo] 
                          objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] 
                          CGRectValue].size;
    
    UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = 
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];

I normally can translate it fine, but I think i'm missing these classes or something. Not sure.

Comment: I also don't know where textView comes from